# Swedish characters in mysql db cause a null result when called for php / html

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters

I have a database setup as utf-8 collation. It contains a table with the same collation which in turn contains a series of varchar variables all in utf-8.

When I try and use the the output of mysql in my html page via the result is null.

Iam making the sql requests with php, using PDO, and the  meta tag for the character set is:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Any idea why values containing **ä å ö** character are returning null?

Comment: I'm also swedish and do these things all day. Problem ususally arise with strange or missing characters when either the admin page, the db or the view page has other encoding than the rest. So in your case also the admin page that saves data into the db should be UTF-8? Have you checked if the characters look good inside the db using phpmyadmin or similar tool?

Comment: Are you setting your charset in your connection string: "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8" ?

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding

```
 mysql_set_charset("UTF8");
```

After you have connected to the database and choosen database. 
I too had a similar problem after trying to convert a mysql db from ISO Latin 1 to UTF8 and adding that line did the trick for me!

Also check so that your php file is saved with UTF8 encoding